# Wordpress DISTINCT query on custom post

Tags: sql, wordpress

Ok this is more of a can it be done question. I have a custom post type that gets queried in a custom function. In my custom post type I have an entry field that accepts years (ie 2011, 2010) and what I need is for my query to just pull the years. So I for instance I have 3 fields, Name, Body, Year. I need the query to pull unique years, so if there are 500 people on the table, I just need to know what specific years exist. so my output would be like 2011, 2010, 2008, 2002, 1995. I could do this with a straight SQL query but is this possible using a wordpress query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, What I ended up doing was just using a standard MySQL Query...

```
$years = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'year_member' AND meta_value <>'' ORDER BY meta_value DESC");

foreach ( $years as $year ) {
$yearCount .= '<option value="'.$year->meta_value.'">'.$year->meta_value.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: In case someone plans to use this with WP multisite, you will have to replace the table names in the query in order to target the right tables :  `"SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->postmeta." WHERE meta_key = 'year_member' AND meta_value <>'' ORDER BY meta_value DESC"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the WordPress DB object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class) to query the database directly:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

I don't know enough about the internals of WordPress to know exactly which tables you'll need to query for your specific situation. The [documentation on the WP tables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) might be of use to you.